# Trouble debugging react native IOS build error "ExpoModulesCore"

Tags: ios, react-native, github-actions, fastlane, xcode13

I've been running into an issue while setting up a build system for react-native using github actions on a M1 mac using fastlane.

I keep running into the following error:

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LbSiteDiary-fpatcoydpffbmtegkcojxxcexlzc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LbSiteDiary/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00025480.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
```

This occurs using Xcode 13.2 and 13.3. I've tried all the usual, such as resetting node_modules + pods.

I'm having trouble getting to the actual error... Any pointers to debugging this are appreciated, as I am currently out of clues...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out more information by looking at the `gym`/`build_app` logfile located in ~/Logs/gym/AppName.log.

This logfile highlighted that the underlying issue was a misconfiguration of nvm.